# Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Yeah, I know the questions is super vague, but in all my years of working with AWS, I've never come across a problem like this!

Anyway, it's very simple. I'm running an EB environment with min 2 max 4 instances. Every day or two, I get an error saying "An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001]." To solve this, I have to rebuild the entire environment every time

> Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) ''. Aborting
>   the operation.Leaving instances running for troubleshooting. Instances
>   have not been re-attached to load balancer.

Has anyone ever run into a problem like this?

Comment: when this happens, what does `system health check` and `instance health check` look like?

Comment: On one instance, I get the above error. Like I mentioned, I have 2 ec2 servers running, so I get this on 1 of the 2 instances almost every other day. System health check appears good though. When I try to restart app server, it fails to do so because it says that 1 instance is unhealthy.

Comment: may be you are hitting soft limit of EC2 instances. It is very hard to say what is going on without looking at what is happening. if it happens to the EC2 in a particular AZ, you may want to try setting a different AZ and see what happens. You may want to contact AWS for this.

Comment: Try logs.  For me, setting a node version of ">=12.0.0" worked for an Amazon Linux environment, but not for Amazon Linux 2 environment.  That's a bit disturbing that a semver range didn't work, but regardless I got it to work by pinning a specific node version.  I only figured that out when I went to `/var/log/eb-engine.log` and found the message "[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Install customer specified node.js version]. Stop running the command. Error: unsupported node version >=12.0.0, please specify any of node versions in [v12.0.0 v12.1.0..."

Comment: Found the issue: My app was printing a ton of logs which caused the server to go down. Solution was to just stop printing logs

Comment: @ChrisJones do you mean your application does loads of logging on cloudwatch.

Answer (score 0):

Per [the OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716895/command-failed-on-instance-an-unexpected-error-has-occurred-errorcode-0000000#comment110360008_47716895) - the issue was caused by excess EBS logging, and remediated by discontinuing logging.

SSHing into the EBS cluster's EC2 instance, and running `cat /var/log/eb-engine.log` may also yield useful information about this type of error.